# Unresolved External Symbols when using gRPC in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, protocol-buffers, grpc

Win10, Visual Studio 15 2017

That's what I've done so far:

- cloned grpc and the submodules from github
- `cmake --build` on grpc
- generated pb.cc and pb.h files from my proto-files
- added *grpc* and *protobuf* to VC++ Directories, Include Directories
- added *zlib*, *grpc* and *protobuf* to VC++ Directories, Library Directories
- added *zlib.lib*, *gpr.lib*, *grpc.lib*, *grpc++.lib* and *libprotobuf.lib* to Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies
- added Preprocessor Definitions: _WIN32_WINNT=0x600; NDEBUG
- changed Runtime Library to /MD

After that my empty project including the pb-files compiled without an error.

Then I wrote some code to use and test grpc but when I try to compile this time, I'm getting several errors like

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _address_sorting_init referenced in function "void __cdecl grpc_resolver_dns_ares_init(void)" (?grpc_resolver_dns_ares_init@@YAXXZ) grpc.lib(dns_resolver_ares.obj)  
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__htons@4 grpc.lib(socket_utils_windows.obj)    
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _ares_gethostbyname referenced in function "struct grpc_ares_request * __cdecl grpc_dns_lookup_ares_continue_after_check_localhost_and_ip_literals_locked(char const *,char const *,char const *,struct grpc_pollset_set *,struct grpc_closure *,struct grpc_lb_addresses * *,bool,char * *,struct grpc_combiner *)" (?grpc_dns_lookup_ares_continue_after_check_localhost_and_ip_literals_locked@@YAPAUgrpc_ares_request@@PBD00PAUgrpc_pollset_set@@PAUgrpc_closure@@PAPAUgrpc_lb_addresses@@_NPAPADPAUgrpc_combiner@@@Z)   grpc.lib(grpc_ares_wrapper.obj)
```

Answer (score 4):

The first symbol "address_sorting_init" comes from the library address sorting present at https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/third_party/address_sorting

The second symbol is from the windows API library "ws2_32", the winsock library from Microsoft.

The third symbol is from the c-ares library: https://c-ares.haxx.se/

All 3 libraries are necessary for building grpc under Windows, so you should add them into your project.

Comment: Thanks. 
I added `ws2_32.lib` to the Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies.
`address_sorting` and `c-ares` are in the third_party folder of grpc therefore I added them as "Include Directories" too, but the error messages stay the same.

Comment: That's not enough to add them as "include directories". You need to actively compile and link them too.

Answer (score 4):

The first error:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _address_sorting_init referenced in function "void __cdecl grpc_resolver_dns_ares_init(void)" (?grpc_resolver_dns_ares_init@@YAXXZ) grpc.lib(dns_resolver_ares.obj)
```

can be resolved by adding the address_sorting.lib. This lib is in the grpc build directory, same as grpc++.lib, grpc.lib and gpr.lib.

The second error:

```
LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__htons@4 grpc.lib(socket_utils_windows.obj)
```

can be resolved by adding ws2_32.lib as per Nicolas suggested.

The third error:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _ares_gethostbyname referenced in function "struct grpc_ares_request * __cdecl grpc_dns_lookup_ares_continue_after_check_localhost_and_ip_literals_locked(char const *,char const *,char const *,struct grpc_pollset_set *,struct grpc_closure *,struct grpc_lb_addresses * *,bool,char * *,struct grpc_combiner *)" (?grpc_dns_lookup_ares_continue_after_check_localhost_and_ip_literals_locked@@YAPAUgrpc_ares_request@@PBD00PAUgrpc_pollset_set@@PAUgrpc_closure@@PAPAUgrpc_lb_addresses@@_NPAPADPAUgrpc_combiner@@@Z)   grpc.lib(grpc_ares_wrapper.obj)
```

can be resolved by adding the cares.lib. You should be able to find this lib file under the third_party\cares\cares\lib directory inside the grpc build directory, no need to get it from elsewhere.

As a summary, suppose your grpc build directory is c:\grpc\.build, here are the libraries required for building a Release version application:

```
c:\grpc\.build\grpc++.lib
c:\grpc\.build\gpr.lib
c:\grpc\.build\grpc.lib
c:\grpc\.build\address_sorting.lib
c:\grpc\.build\third_party\protobuf\libprotobuf.lib
c:\grpc\.build\third_party\zlib.lib
c:\grpc\.build\third_party\cares\cares\lib\cares.lib
ws2_32.lib
```

If you want to build a Debug version of your application, please build a Debug version of grpc first, and then reference the libraries from the grpc debug version. To build a debug version with Ninja:

```
> md .debug
> cd .debug
> call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x64
> cmake .. -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
> cmake --build .
```

Please change above directory of vcvarsall.bat according to your Visual Studio installation.

Please also note the Debug version of protobuf library file's name is libprotobufd.lib, not libprotobuf.lib.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to add all these libs to resolve all unresolved external symbols issues

```
libprotobufd.lib
gpr.lib
grpc.lib
grpc++.lib
grpc++_reflection.lib
address_sorting.lib
ws2_32.lib
cares.lib
zlibstaticd.lib
upb.lib
ssl.lib
crypto.lib
absl_bad_any_cast_impl.lib
absl_bad_optional_access.lib
absl_bad_variant_access.lib
absl_base.lib
absl_city.lib
absl_civil_time.lib
absl_cord.lib
absl_debugging_internal.lib
absl_demangle_internal.lib
absl_dynamic_annotations.lib
absl_examine_stack.lib
absl_exponential_biased.lib
absl_failure_signal_handler.lib
absl_flags.lib
absl_flags_config.lib
absl_flags_internal.lib
absl_flags_marshalling.lib
absl_flags_parse.lib
absl_flags_program_name.lib
absl_flags_registry.lib
absl_flags_usage.lib
absl_flags_usage_internal.lib
absl_graphcycles_internal.lib
absl_hash.lib
absl_hashtablez_sampler.lib
absl_int128.lib
absl_leak_check.lib
absl_leak_check_disable.lib
absl_log_severity.lib
absl_malloc_internal.lib
absl_periodic_sampler.lib
absl_random_distributions.lib
absl_random_internal_distribution_test_util.lib
absl_random_internal_pool_urbg.lib
absl_random_internal_randen.lib
absl_random_internal_randen_hwaes.lib
absl_random_internal_randen_hwaes_impl.lib
absl_random_internal_randen_slow.lib
absl_random_internal_seed_material.lib
absl_random_seed_gen_exception.lib
absl_random_seed_sequences.lib
absl_raw_hash_set.lib
absl_raw_logging_internal.lib
absl_scoped_set_env.lib
absl_spinlock_wait.lib
absl_stacktrace.lib
absl_status.lib
absl_strings.lib
absl_strings_internal.lib
absl_str_format_internal.lib
absl_symbolize.lib
absl_synchronization.lib
absl_throw_delegate.lib
absl_time.lib
absl_time_zone.lib
```

Answer (score 0):

With these libraries linked it works for me (in VS2015 and Win10):

`grpc++, grpc, gpr, libprotobuf, zlibstatic, ssl, crypto`

The last 2 are in the third_party/boringssl directory.

Answer (score 0):

I hit this using conan to build grpc. I found it much easier change the grpc conanfile to use [CMake install](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/howtos/cmake_install.html) to collect all the necessary libraries. The GRPC authors maintain the `install` target for this purpose.

Conan tools' `collect_libs` ([docs](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/tools.html#tools-collect-libs)) also means you don't have to explicitly list them all yourself; they get generated into the props and then visual studio uses them from there.